# Transferring data if it starts with a specific number

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that transfers data over to another sheet if it matches the condition. My problem is this part of the code:

```
If (wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow, 12) = "262015" Then
```

I want to transfer the data but only if it starts with 262015, I know you can use "left", but i keep getting errors when I try to implement it in my code. I hope someone can help me.

```
Sub transferstudent()
Dim wsIn As Worksheet
Dim wsOut As Worksheet


Set wsIn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Base")
Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Students")


wsOut.Cells(1, 1) = wsIn.Cells(1, 1) 
wsOut.Cells(1, 2) = wsIn.Cells(1, 8) 
wsOut.Cells(1, 3) = wsIn.Cells(1, 9) 

Dim lLastInputRow As Long
Dim lCurrentInputRow As Long
Dim lCurrentOutputRow As Long

lLastInputRow = wsIn.Cells(wsIn.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCurrentOutputRow = 2

For lCurrentInputRow = lLastInputRow To 2 Step -1

If (wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow, 12) = "262015" Then

wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow, 1) = wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow, 1) 
wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow, 2) = wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow, 8) 
wsOut.Cells(lCurrentOutputRow, 3) = wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow, 9) 
lCurrentOutputRow = lCurrentOutputRow + 1


End If
Next lCurrentInputRow


wsIn.Select
Set wsIn = Nothing
Set wsOut = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `If Left$(wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow, 12), 6) = "262015" Then`

Comment: Thank you very much! this is exactly what i was looking for :-)

Answer (score 1):

your code is missing ")" here it is:

```
If (Left(wsIn.Cells(lCurrentInputRow, 12), 6)) = "262015" Then
    MsgBox "hi"
End If
```